# How to look into generic tList during Delphi debugging

Tags: delphi, debugging, generics, generic-list, tlist

I use Delphi 10.3.1 COMMUNITY version and can't look into generic tList while I debug the project.

I know the latest version of Delphi doesn't support the old-typed debug feature which allows to look into generic tList. So I used tList.List in the following code to evaluate the tList.

In `tList<tRecord>.List` I can look into it but can't do it in `tList<Integer>.List`.

[image]

```
type
  tRecord = record
    Field: Integer;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  _Record: tRecord;
  _List1: TList<tRecord>;
  _List2: TList<Integer>;
  i: Integer;
begin
  _List1 := TList<tRecord>.Create;
  _List2 := TList<Integer>.Create;

  for i := 0 to 4 do
  begin
    _Record.Field := i;

    _List1.Add(_Record);
    _List2.Add(i);
  end;

  Caption := IntToStr(_List1.List[0].Field) + IntToStr(_List2.List[0]);

  _List1.Free;
  _List2.Free;
end;
```

How can I look into `tList<Integer>` during the debugging?

Comment: What does "look into during debugging" mean to you?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I added an image. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually it should be possible to see the lists contained array over the `List` property. Internally there is only a field of type `Pointer` unlike before 10.3 when it was of type `TArray<T>`.

This is what I see when I put a breakpoint into the line where it assigns to `Caption` and put those two entries into my watches:

[image]

Update: It looks like the Linker is responsible for the issue you are experiencing here. When you uncheck the option to "allow side effects and function calls" in the watch

[image]

the watch window will show this:

[image]

I have seen this behavior before when using generics that are only specified in the implementation part of the unit (FWIW when I tried to repro this the first time I did not put the code you posted into a VCL project but into a console dpr and that one does not have an implementation part so I did not see this behavior).

To force the linker to not to remove the symbol or the debugger to actually see it (because even if I disable inlining to force the GetList method to stay the watch window will tell me that it got removed) you can simply put some dummy type into the `interface` part of this or any other unit.

```
type TDummy = TList<Integer>;
```

This will cause the debugger to see the symbol and see the values in the watches window.

Comment: It's wierd. I added an image above. Am I missing a debug option or something? I didn't change any debug setting at all. Thanks.

Comment: You were right. Putting the declaration of tList<Integer> in interface part solved the problem. What's wrong with the Delphi?

Comment: Did anyone open an official report with embarcadero on this issue, while the work-around works, the solution is far from obvious.

Comment: Well, the core issue that requires using these watches has been reported by me: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22014